# Qt: launch a message box periodically with crontab in ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, x11, xauth

I am trying to launch a Qt message box every minute. I added a line in crontab to run the Qt program's executable and redirected the error output to a file in my home directory. 
There is no problem with the Qt program that launches the message box because I tested it, but when I try to launch it with crontab the following error arises:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I checked that over the internet and found a thread that might be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148945/could-not-connect-to-display-in-one-user-account/149026#149026

I believe the first response gives the solution but it's not clear.
It suggests to use x11 to share the desktop and xauth to add security measures but doesn't specify how to configure them. I have xauth already installed but the error persists.
Any ideas about how to solve this problem?

Comment: What about pasting the crontab line?

Comment: */1 * * * * /home/salwa/computing/cpp/horloge 2>> /home/salwa/cron.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the DISPLAY environment is missing. I suggest you wrap your application in a wrapper script (let's call it horloge.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
DISPLAY=:0
export DISPLAY
/home/salwa/computing/cpp/horloge
```

Then put the horloge.sh in your crontab. Don't forget to do a `chmod u+x horloge.sh` so that the script is executable.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot JvO, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Putting this in a script is basically unnecessary. The equivalent one-liner would be simply `DISPLAY=:0 /home/salwa/computing/cpp/horloge`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user that launches your app in the crontab line is you. Otherwise, it may not have permissions to use the X server.

Comment: Thanks Alesegdia for your reply. Actually I am a beginner and this is the first time I use Qt. I am the user that has created the line in crontab and that launches the app (I mean I do everything while logged in the same user session). Can you please give me a beginners explanation of the term X server?

Comment: Sure. Do you know about windows managers? i.e.: Gnome, Kde... if so, they're **clients** that need to be run inside an **X server**. Usually, your OS is automatically configured to launch one server at startup, and the client of your choice runs there.

You could also paste your crontab line for completion.